# Whats the iOS equivalent of a canvas?

Tags: android, ios, ios5, interface-builder

im porting my OGLES app to iOS from Android, and dynamically make an image to bind as a texture like so:

```
        Bitmap overlayBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(512,512, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        // get a canvas to paint over the bitmap
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlayBitmap);
        overlayBitmap.eraseColor(0);
        // Draw the text
        TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
        textPaint.setTextSize(30);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setARGB(0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        textPaint.measureText(stopName);

        // get a background image from resources
        // note the image format must match the bitmap format
        cap.setBounds(0,0,8,49);
        cap.draw(canvas);
        overlayBackground.setBounds(8,0, (int) textPaint.measureText(stopName)+8, 49);
        overlayBackground.draw(canvas); // draw the background to our bitmap
        Rect overlayBounds=overlayBackground.getBounds();
        spike.setBounds((((overlayBounds.right+8)/2)-((21/2))),48,(((overlayBounds.right+8)/2)+((21/2))),69);
        spike.draw(canvas);
        capR.setBounds(overlayBounds.right,0,overlayBounds.right+8,49);     
        capR.draw(canvas);
        // draw the text centered
        canvas.drawText(stopName,8,33, textPaint);
```

Comment: I believe it's an instance of EAGLContext

Comment: I think iOS' CoreGraphics Apis are equivalent to translate your this code, which can help to create a custom image with texture drawing.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do the opposite. My question is: where did `cap` and `spike` come from?

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent is by using Quartz 2D and

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions();
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); //get the context we just made above
```

then you can export the context as a UIImage.